# WPF Culture issue

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo, culture, currentculture

I would like to display in the main page of my app the date in the french format:
(dd/MM/yyyy)
I work with Entity Framework objects and dates are properties of an entity list which is binded to a combobox in the xaml file.

I manage to get through this by adding this code when my app starts:

```cs
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

BUT I get a new problem with this add : All my decimal numbers use comma instead of using dot in the other pages of my app...ma app doesn't work anymore with this change...

So could you give me a solution which solve the problem in a global way...
To summarize I need French Date format and decimal with dot. 
I would prefer to not have to change the culture for each line of my code.

I already tried to add this line in the concerned page but It didn't work.

```cs
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is change the formatting of dates in a single control, then changing the application-wide locale is *not* the way to do that.  Set a custom `ItemTemplate` on your `ComboBox`, and set the `StringFormat` on your `Binding` to `'dd/MM/yyyy'`.

If you *really* need to change the date format across your entire application, but you want to leave the other formats untouched, you can apply a custom locale at startup based on the current one, but getting it to work properly in WPF requires some nasty reflection.

```
var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
if (currentCulture.IsReadOnly)
    currentCulture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture.IetfLanguageTag, true);

currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

// ...adjust other patterns accordingly...

// WARNING: Ugly reflection hacking ahead...

var defaultValueField = typeof(PropertyMetadata).GetField(
    "_defaultValue",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var equivalentCultureField = typeof(XmlLanguage).GetField(
    "_equivalentCulture",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

if (defaultValueField != null &&
    equivalentCultureField != null)
{
    var xmlLanguage = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(currentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);

    equivalentCultureField.SetValue(
        xmlLanguage,
        currentCulture);

    defaultValueField.SetValue(
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.DefaultMetadata,
        xmlLanguage);
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
```

Be sure to do that from your main thread, as early in the startup process as possible.  Be aware, however, that this *will* affect *the entire program* and not just the WPF visual bits.  For example, it may impact the timestamp format in your logs, among other things.

On a personal note, as someone who works in a company with multiple locales, I find it much less confusing to simply use the ISO standard `yyyy-MM-dd` format for all dates.  The `d/MM/yyyy` and `MM/d/yyyy` formats need to go away.

Comment: I already tried to add the stringFormat but It didn't work and the solution that was given to me to make it works was to add the code : FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag))); I can't find anymore where I have readen this but after I had added the line the binding and the stringFormat on my control worked...

Comment: Yes, that code will change the default display culture of the WPF elements.  My code above makes a similar change, but I took it a step further to redirect the XmlLanguage to a custom culture.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have different resource files with same keys and values based on region and use culture  to load respective region value